# Cannot see the string metrics output from Golang REST API in Prometheus

Tags: go, prometheus, rest

I am trying to create a REST API using Golang to provide metrics to Prometheus. I already have REST API available that is available on for example: http://localhost:46743/prometheusJobs The API works fine after testing on swagger, I get the response content as followed, for now it's just the sample of text format I got from Prometheus documentation.

[image: swagger]

This is my Go function to output (provide) the metrics to Prometheus, for now it's just a string as I would like to test first:

```
func GetPrometheusJobsHandler(params jobs_management.GetPrometheusJobsParams) middleware.Responder {
    ret := ""

    // TODO : construct metrics
    ret += `
# HELP http_requests_total The total number of HTTP requests.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{method="post",code="200"} 1027 1395066363000
http_requests_total{method="post",code="400"}    3 1395066363000
    `

    return jobs_management.NewGetPrometheusJobsOK().WithPayload(ret)
}
```

In my Prometheus, I am successfully connected to this API as the state shows as `UP` now:

[image: promtarget]

And, the value shows as `1`

[image: promtarget2]

However, I don't see the string I define as output in my Go function above in the drop down here in Prometheus:

[image: dropdownprom]

Could you please let me know what I did wrong? or is this NOT the right way to provide the metrics to Prometheus and I must use the Golang libraries (https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/)? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think these are valid prometheus metrics:

```
# HELP http_requests_total The total number of HTTP requests.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{method="post",code="200"} 1027 1395066363000
http_requests_total{method="post",code="400"}    3 1395066363000
```

Can you try with :

```
# HELP http_requests_total The total number of HTTP requests.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{method="post",code="200"} 1027 
http_requests_total{method="post",code="400"} 3
```

Using the official go client to provide such metrics would ensure their validity